# Can we send PDF file from AngularJS client to NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pdf, jspdf

Using [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) I have generated `pdf` file on the client side (AngularJS). I am able to successfully download the file. Now I have another function to send the `pdf via email` to user email address.

**Problem:**

When user clicks on `send email` button, the pdf which I created using `jspdf` should be uploaded to server and there I should be able to attach the pdf file which I got from client to email. Is it possible to do the same? I am not sure whether we can do this or not.

Can we send the doc object in `var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');` to `nodejs` then render it and finally attach to the email?

If the above task is not possible then let me know about other possibilities.

**P.S:** I am using [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) for sending emails.

Comment: You can send files with AngularJS using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) API

Comment: @rahilwazir But will the file be in the same format .. I mean PDF in this case after sending to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have forked a sample code for both client and server side code, tested and working perfectly. Please modify according to your need.

**Server side:** Hosted on cloud9 for testing - Hence it takes the public ip and port provided by the provider via `process` object. Change the listener according to your hosting environment.

**Note:** Please read the inline comment for better understanding

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var formidable = require('formidable'),
form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

app.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log("File received:\nName:"+files.pdf.name+"\ntype:"+files.pdf.type);
    });

    form.on('end', function() {
        /* this.openedFiles[0].path -- object Contains the path to the file uploaded
        ------- Use NodeMailer to process this file or attach to the mail-----------------*/
        console.log("PDF raw data:"+ fs.readFileSync(this.openedFiles[0].path, "utf8"));
        res.status(200).send("thank you");
    });
})
.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
    console.log('Server app listening');
});
```

**Client Side:** [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/nirus/87qgh59z/)

**Note:** I didn't paste `imgData` as SO has character limit. Refer the fiddler link for the client code. Change the request URL to your server. Client side uses Blob API which is an HTML5 standard. so test it on HTML5 compliant browsers.

```
var imgData = [[**Copy the same image provided by JSpdf example. Check the fiddler for complete code**]]

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);

var data = new Blob([doc.output()], {
    type: 'application/pdf'
});

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("pdf", data, "myfile.pdf");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "https://saltjs-nirus.c9.io"); // Change to your server
request.send(formData);
```

---

**References:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects
- https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable
- http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/ (Example reference)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: Be sure to check on modern browsers that implements Blob API

Comment: Sry for the late response. I am having some issue with email sending. 
File upload seems to be working though there is some problem with image rendering in the pdf. The image is getting blurred in black & white. Other than that rest of the data is intact. An idea about this problem?

Comment: Thats totally a different question thread. You can check the pdf file locally, if it has the same problem better raise an issue here: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues . Attach the image and the code you tried to render, so that author of the lib can address it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the response .. Will check that issue.