# Node.js : throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Tags: node.js, pdf, express, file-upload

I am writing this after searching all the existing topics on this error. No doubt it has helped a lot to understand me this error, but unfortunately, I am not able to solve my problem. I want to upload a pdf file generated from an angular app to my server and I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525152/can-we-send-pdf-file-from-angularjs-client-to-nodejs-server) code. Initially I got error as "XMLHttpRequest cannot load . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."

To resolve this I used following code to create .htaccess file on c:/wamp/www/ location. (note- I am using WAMP server)

`

```js
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|js|json|html|css|pdf)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Now I am getting below error :

```
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\node_apps\pp_app\node_modules\express\lib\respo
nse.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\node_apps\pp_app\node_modules\express\lib\respons
e.js:163:12)
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (C:\node_apps\pp_app\index.js:18:25)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (C:\node_apps\pp_app\node_modules\formidable\lib\i
ncoming_form.js:553:8)
    at C:\node_apps\pp_app\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:230:12
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\node_apps\pp_app\node_modules\formidable\lib\
file.js:70:5)
    at WriteStream.g (events.js:199:16)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:129:20)
```

After having this error, node server ends and hence I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on my application console. I know I am doing something wrong, but not able to understand it where and how as I am new to node.js and express.js.

Can you please help !

client and server side code :https://jsfiddle.net/0paL9bfb/5/

FYI- A file is uploaded in temp folder on server, but the type is 'file' and not 'pdf' and the images are are not rendering proper in pdf. The added text is rendering fine.

Comment: _Can\'t set headers after they are sent._ just means that you send response headers like res.end() or something like that *more* than one time, which are obviously incorrect.

Comment: @loadaverage : But in my code, I am no where using response headers more than once. its only once...   "res.status(200).send("thank you");" So confusing me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems all is OK. Try this for demo

[Client](http://jsfiddle.net/0paL9bfb/12/) and  [Server](https://jsfiddle.net/edt1f738/)

btw, this `files.pdf.name` is dangerous   :)

Comment: Thanks @loadaverage. But the pdf which is uploaded on the server does not render images. Text is coming fine. I know this is different issue from what I posted yesterday, but just asking if you have any idea. PDF on local machine renders fine.

Comment: Updated client and server code for your reference : https://jsfiddle.net/L09jnmbn/1/

Comment: Ahh..I found  var data =  doc.output("blob"); did the trick. Was able to save the generated pdf successfully on the server, but doing the same second time[means calling createPdf() to generate another pdf], again gave me   
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Comment: I think this is some incorrect stuff on the client side (pdf lib) 'cause as u see - server side is ok

Comment: Yeah...trying to fix it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a middleware to Express to add those headers:

### In your server file:

**(In your JsFiddle, this goes on line 43.)**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var pattern = /.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|js|json|html|css|pdf)/
  if (pattern.test(req.url)) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  }
  next();
});
```

This will look at all incoming requests and adds the CORS headers if the request contains the supplied regexp.

You can then delete the .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks @ Mikko Tormala